# Python: Get importing module's details from within imported module

Tags: python, django, rest, import

I'm writing a piece of reusable code to import where I need it, but it needs some info about what is importing it. I have a workaround that does what I want, but it's a bit ugly. Is there a better way?

Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing.

**What I want:** Import a method and use it, but look at f in mod2. It needs some info from the importing module.

mod1:

```
from mod2 import f
f(...)
```

mod2:

```
from things_i_want import parent_module, importing_module
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    from importing_module.parent_module import models
    # ... do some stuff with it, including populating v with a string

    v = 'some_string'
    m = getattr(importing_module, v, None)
    if callable(m)
        return m(*args, **kwargs)
```

**My ugly workaround:**

mod1:

```
from mod2 import f as _f
def f(*a, **k):return _f(__name__, globals(), *a, **k)
f(...)
```

mod2:

```
def f(module_name, globs, *args, **kwargs):
    # find parent modules path
    parent_module_path = module_name.split('.')[0:-1]
    # find models modules path
    models_path = parent_module_path + ['models',]
    # import it
    models = __import__('.'.join(models_path), {}, {}, [''])
    # ... do some stuff with it, including populating v with a string

    v = 'some_string'
    if v in globs:
        return globs[v](*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It might help if you gave us a little background on *why* you want this, as it's a pretty unusual request.

Comment: This is fraught with danger.  Imported modules should not be "aware" of their context by magical means.  It's a testing nightmare.  You want to follow what's called "Dependency Injection" where you explicitly tell the imported module what it needs to know.  No magical "discovery" of context.

Comment: To give some context:
This is in a Django webapp. I have a method I call in my urlconf that maps RESTful URLs all to a method in a models views. This method looks at request.method then checks for the existence of a method in the views like foo_delete and calls it, or runs a default action for that url and request method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a bad idea, because modules are cached.

So if another module, say, `mod3.py`, also imports `mod2`, it will get the same `mod2` object of the first time. The module is not reimported.

Maybe you imported some other module that imported `mod2` before importing `mod2` yourself, then you're not the one importing `mod2` anymore. Modules are imported only once.

So instead of trying to get who imported the module, you should use another, reusable approach. Perhaps using classes and passing the instance around?

Comment: So my ugly workaround might not be so ugly?
See comment above for context.

Comment: It is ugly because it tries to hide its intents. It's better to be explicit than implicit. Why don't you pass a class to f() that contains the delete/insert/update/select methods inside it? Also, Django uses strings 'project.app.myfun' everywhere to refer to functions, so there is some function somewhere in django that takes a string and returns the actual function object it is refering. Why not use that?

Comment: Good point. There is a function (get_app)which takes a string like "project.app" and returns it, there may be one that goes deeper. Or I could use __import__?
I'd rather not wrap them in a class because I want them to remain the the view file so that other URLs can point to them, and so that I'm changing Django as little as possible.